# Call an onclick method from one view to another iphoneprogess hub iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a view with a button which downloads files when clicked.

Question I have is is it possible to call that click method from another view>

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a method there. Something like onBtnClk. You can create in another view an instance of your viewController, that contains this method and send [myViewController onBtnClk].

Comment: Will this do it?

QueueViewController *queueViewController = [QueueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Queue" bundle:nil];
[queueViewController onBtnClk]
self.view=queueViewController.view;

Comment: By the way this is not good solution. You should realize your download in some other class and just call it wherever you want.

Comment: And this is unnecessary to set self.view in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good case to have some other class(maybe a singleton?) handle downloads, then have your click: method interact with the downloading class.

I know that everyone hates singletons, but this may be a good time to use one.